# Android market intent doesn't work, but web link does?

Tags: android, google-play

this doesn't work

```
    Intent marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android"));
    startActivity(marketLaunch);
```

but the web link does....

https://market.android.com/details?id=myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android

this is super confusing, any ideas?

Comment: If you are using emulator this wont work as emulator doesnt have market app installed on it

Comment: OK, this is weird.  I have an archos A32 as a test device and the app isn't found on that device's marketplace, but it IS found on my Optimus S test phone....  Are the available apps different on different devices??  I guess I'll just toast the user when they hit my paid app link and tell them that the device isn't available for their device?  The archos is running 2.2.1 and the optimus is running 2.2.2

Comment: Hmm..I guess something to do with your application manifest which the market checks to decide whether the app is available on a particular device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the available apps differ from device to device...

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure this helps but just for your knowledge (though it seems in your attached example code that everything you did is fine) the application ID (=your package: myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android) has to be written exactly in the same case as it is in the android market.

For example this code would **not** work:

```
marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=myvirtualhealthcheck.com.android"));
startActivity(marketLaunch);
```

in the above example the id is in lower case, as oppose to the actual id in android market which is myVirtualHealthCheck.com.Android, hence using it will result with "page not found error"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on [Android Market filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html):

> When a user searches or browses in Android Market on an Android device, the results are filtered based on which applications are compatible with that device. For example, if an application requires a camera (as specified in the application manifest file), then Android Market will not show the app on any device that does not have a camera.
>
> Declarations in the manifest file that are compared to the device's configuration is not the only part of how applications are filtered. Filtering might also occur due to the user's country and carrier, the presence or absence of a SIM card, and other factors.